# Scala add list[map] to map

Tags: scala

I want to convert

```
List(Map(AAA -> 1111), Map(BBB -> 22222), Map(CCC -> 3333))
```

to

```
Map( AAA->111, BBB-> 222, CCC->333)
```

I already saw some answers(`flatten.toMap` or `reduce(_ ++ _)`), but they are not working well.

- I should not make 'var' and new functions

Comment: in expected output, do you want to change the value. I see `1111` is converted to `111`.
`flatten.map` works, what is the issue you are facing with that?

Comment: No implicit arguments of type: ((type1, type2)) => IterableOnce[B_]
This message appears.

Comment: Ok, I dont see any issue with scala 2.13. Maybe you are on lower version

Comment: Why aren't those options working well? Are you having a compile error or a runtime error or a different output?

Comment: Sorry for everyone...
The problem was wrong type-matching

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use a flatMap with an `identity` function to conver it to a List of tuples and then toMap to make it a map again

```
l.flatMap(identity).toMap
```

An other option

```
l.flatten.toMap
```

**result:**

```
Map(AAA -> 1111, BBB -> 22222, CCC -> 3333)
```

Comment: I would `l.iterator.flatten.toMap`